# Convert subrip subtitles ( .srt ) to substation alpha subtitles (.ass)

Tags: srt

I'am trying to convert a subrip sub (.srt) to substation alpha sub (.ass), in Linux.
How to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [ffmpeg.org](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HowToConvertSubtitleToASS)

```
ffmpeg -i sub.srt sub.ass
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Well there is not a lot more to say, other tools provide this functionnality, but not as simple as straight forward as this command.